# How to extract numbers from a string using regix (re) module

Tags: python

How to extract numbers from a string like string

```
import re
re.findall(r'\d+', 'hello 42 I\'m a 32 string 30')
['42', '32', '30']
```

NB: Not wanted to do

```
for i in ls:
   print (i,end='')

type(i) is int
```

Expected

`42`,`32`,`30`

Comment: String objects have a method `join` for that.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Are you trying to convert them to `int`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
result = ', '.join(re.findall(r'\d+', 'hello 42 I\'m a 32 string 30'))
print(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `map` with `int` and unpack the result in `print()` function

```
print(*map(int, re.findall(r'\d+', 'hello 42 I\'m a 32 string 30')), sep=",")
```

OR if you don't want to convert the numbers to int

```
print(*re.findall(r'\d+', 'hello 42 I\'m a 32 string 30'), sep=",")
```

Output

```
42,32,30
```